# Javascript: Passing variable to function breaks function

Tags: javascript

I am using an onsubmit variable to ensure that the user really means to delete something, however as soon as I put a value in the parenthesis inside the onsubmit it no longer calls the confirm box.

Code:

```
onClick="confirmSubmit(abc)"
```

Doesn't work but the following:

```
onClick="confirmSubmit()"
```

Does work

Function:

```
    function confirmSubmit(category)
{
var category = category;
var agree=confirm("Are you sure you wish to DELETE" + category + " and all of its subcategories and photos?");
if (agree)
    return true ;
else
    return false ;
}
```

Comment: `confirm()` returns a boolean, so you can shorten your return statement by just returning the return value of the confirm. `return confirm("Are you sure...");`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need quotes around your `abc`:

```
onclick="confirmSubmit('abc')"
```

Without them you are trying to pass a variable, `abc`, which doesn't exist and triggers an error

Comment: The problem is these are built by PHP and thus both styles of quotes are already reserved. I have used PHP to convert the variable to a string but to no avail.

Comment: So escape the quote:  `echo 'onclick="confirmSubmit(\'abc\')"';`

Comment: Ok but I need this to work with a variable... `onClick="confirmSubmit('.$row['Cname'].')` is true code

Comment: `'...(\'' . $row['CName'] . '\')'`

Comment: Thanks now the function runs but the variable passed to does not show in the dialog, the variable is definitely contains something because I echo it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

`onClick="confirmSubmit(abc)"` is trying to pass the variable `abc`, if you intend to pass a string with the value "abc" then do this:

`onClick="confirmSubmit('abc')"`

Answer (score 1):

```
function confirmSubmit(category)  
{  var category = category;
```

And you've declared "category" twice! Once in the function header and then as a function variable in the next line! What for?

Comment: That was when it failed at first I was just trying out different things, it has since been removed :), can you see why category would be empty now I've followed cwolves advice? The function runs but there is a blank space in place of the variable category.

Comment: Can't you shorten and simplify the return to... return confirm("Are you sure you wish to DELETE" + category + " and all of its subcategories and photos?")==true;

Answer (score 0):

You're try to pass the variable `abc` (which does not exist) to the function. 
Do:
    `onclick="return confirmSubmit('abc');"`